# Call to undefined method Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession::SetClientCustomerId()

Tags: php

I am using google Adword sdk. After upgrading ;library facing this error.

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined method
>   Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession::SetClientCustomerId()

Line of code which gives this error is as given below.

```
$user->SetClientCustomerId($account_google->getGoogleAdwordAccount());
```

have any one faced this issue while using Adword sdk.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `SetClientCustomerId()` is not a method of the `AdWordsSession` class. It is however, part of the `AdWordsSessionBuilder` class.

If you need update `ClientCustomerId`, simply renew your session - something like:

```
    $your_session = ( new AdWordsSessionBuilder() )
        ->fromFile( 'adsapi_php.ini' )
        ->withClientCustomerId( $yourNewClientCustomerId )
        ->withOAuth2Credential( $oAuth2Credential )
        ->build();
```